# Timeout does not work in expect script

Tags: linux, expect

I created the following expect script in order to automate logging into a VPN:

```
 #!/usr/bin/expect

 set PASS [lindex $argv 0]

 set timeout 10
 spawn  vpnc
 expect    :            {send $PASS\r}
 expect eof
```

However, when I give wrong password argument, the expected 10 second does not occur.

Why does this 10 second timeout not occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would explicitly expect the timeout:

```
set timeout 10
spawn  vpnc
expect :
send [lindex $argv 0]\r
expect {
    timeout {error "incorrect password"; exit 1}
    eof
}
```

Comment: so what is the point? , how you solve this? , where I am wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that, while you're expecting "eof", when the timeout occurs, your script does nothing with it. Did you test my code? Obviously "the point" is that I'm trying to help you with your problem. What are you going to do with my efforts?

Comment: ok I will check your solution on my machine ,, I will return as soon to give you what was happend -:)

Comment: VOTE FOR YOU ITS WORKS